# kotlin, id is not not recognize in main activity

Tags: android, kotlin

im doing online courses doing BMI(body mass index) app
i know the basic, i installed it kotlin plugins but id mention in XML not not recognize in main activity saying Unresolved reference: calculate_button,Unresolved reference: weight_edit_text
,Unresolved reference: height_edit_text
,Unresolved reference: bmi_text_view

```
   calculate_button.setOnClickListener {


        val weight = weight_edit_text.text.toString().toFloat()

        val height = height_edit_text.text.toString().toFloat()

        val myBMI = weight / height * height


        bmi_text_view.text = myBMI.toString()
    }
}
```

}enter code here

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to use synthetic view references, part of Kotlin Android Extensions, which is deprecated and no longer included in new products. Read here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding/migration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options:

1. used findviewbyid<EditText/Button>(R.id.yourEditText/Button)
   Ex.

   val weight = findViewById(R.id.weight_edit_text)

weight.text.toString().toFloat()

2. Or use the deprecated Kotlin extensions. To do this..

In your **project** build grade under dependencies

```
classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions:$kotlin_version"
```

In your **module** build grade under plugins

```
id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
```

*Note this is deprecated and probably advised to use viewbinding as noted in the comment by TenFour04.